# RShiny download Rmd report with reactive filters: cannot apply filters to report

Tags: r, shiny, download, r-markdown, reactive

I have an example RShiny app with reactive filters that I added download button buttons for downloading .csv and Rmd report (as html). The download report handler links to a parameterized Rmd file.

I have no problem downloading the filtered data in .csv. I can also download the report, but it is not filtered with the slider/selection inputs.

I think it is something with the params arg, but I am getting stuck on that. Below is the RShiny code and the .Rmd code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggthemes)

setwd(wd)

cat1 <- as.character(c(1:10))
cat2 <-  c("a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b")
cat3 <- c(1,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27)
cat4 <- c("one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "four", "three", "five", "three", "four")

df <- data.frame(cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)



#--------------------------------------------
ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    
    theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "lumen"),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(9, 
             offset = 0, 
             span("Example")
             )
      ),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      position = "left",

      sidebarPanel(
        width = 3, offset = 0,
        
        selectInput("set",
                    label = "Set:",
                    choices = c("All", unique(df$cat2))
                    ),
        
        sliderInput(inputId = "age", 
                    label = "Choose Age Range:", 
                    min = min(df$cat3), 
                    max = 30,
                    value=c(1, 30),
                    step = 3)
        ),
    
      mainPanel(
        width = 9, offset=0,
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel('Dashboard',
                   br(),
        
                   dashboardPage(
                     dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
                     dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                     dashboardBody(
                       box(
                         title = "Group distribution",
                         width = 6,
                         background = "light-blue",
                         solidHeader = TRUE,
                         plotOutput("group_bar", height = 300)
                       )
                     )
                   ),
                   downloadButton("data", "Download Data"),
                   downloadButton("report", "Download Report")
          )
        )
        )
      )
    )
      
      
      
      
      

#------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rval_filters <- reactive({
    req(input$set)
    req(input$age)

    data <- df
    
    #filter data set 
    if (input$set != "All"){
      data <- data %>%
        filter(cat2 %in% input$set)
    } else {
      data 
    }
    
    #filter based on age range
    data <- data %>%
      filter(cat3 >= input$age[1] & cat3 <= input$age[2])
    data
    
  })
    
    
    # plot by group
    output$group_bar <- renderPlot({
      group <- rval_filters() %>%
      #summarize 
        group_by(cat4) %>%
        summarise(n = n())

      plot_bar <- ggplot(group, aes(x= n, y = reorder(cat4, n))) +
        geom_bar(stat= "identity",fill = "#4C7A99") +
        theme_minimal()+
        labs(x = "Count") 
      
      plot_bar
      
    })
    
  output$data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste0("report", ".csv")
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(rval_filters(), file)
    }
  )
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(
        n = df,
        plot = plot_bar
      )
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )

}
    
# Run app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

````
#-----------RMD----------------------
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
  plot: "NULL"
---

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
````

```
# A plot 

params$plot
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you pass `plot_bar` to the `plot` parameter of the Rmd. However, `plot_bar` is a local variable defined and only accessible within your `renderPlot`. To export your plot use a `reactive` to create the plot. This `reactive` could then be called inside `renderPlot` to plot your chart and also be passed to the `plot` parameter of the Rmd:

```
  plot_bar <- reactive({
    group <- rval_filters() %>%
      group_by(cat4) %>%
      summarise(n = n())
    
    plot_bar <- ggplot(group, aes(x = n, y = reorder(cat4, n))) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#4C7A99") +
      theme_minimal() +
      labs(x = "Count")
    
    plot_bar
  })
  
  # plot by group
  output$group_bar <- renderPlot({
    plot_bar()
  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(
        n = df,
        plot = plot_bar()
      )

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport,
        output_file = file,
        params = params,
        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
```

[image]